# Get emails as array from an array of hashes by matching criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes like this:

```
arr = [
  { email: 'prathab@hotmail.in', valid: true },
  { email: 'another@gmail.com', valid: false },
  { email: 'hello@hotmail.in', has_many: 10, valid: true}
]
```

What I need is to get list of emails by `valid: true`.

**Expected result:**

```
=> ["prathab@hotmail.in", "hello@hotmail.in"]
# another@gmail.com is not in the list because it's valid is false.
```

How can I check for such hash in the array without using `each` loop?

Currently I am doing this:

```
found = []
arr.each do|v|
  if v[:valid] == true
    found << v[:email]
  end
end
```

**Note**: `email` and `valid` can be re-ordered or can have other keys along with them. I just minimized the example.

Comment: try with `arr.select { |email| email[:valid] }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `select`:

```
valids = arr.select { |hash| hash[:valid] }
emails = valids.map { |hash| hash[:email] }
```

Comment: Ah no. This returns all values. I need only email values. Look at the expected result in my question.

Comment: @Pratha simply add a `.map { |hash| hash.fetch(:email) }` after the `select` block to grab the `email` value for each hash and build an array out of it

Answer (score 1):

Just for having an alternative way:

```
arr.collect { |h| h[:email] if h[:valid] }.compact
#=> ["prathab@hotmail.in", "hello@hotmail.in"]
```